# Lost in the processs of solving a separable differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integration

I'm reading Differential Equations for Dummies and in the part dealing with seperable equations there's this equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2}{(2-y^2)}$ to solve. So they do:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2}{(2-y^2)}$$

then $(2-y^2)\,dy=x^2dx$

Or

$$-x^2+(2-y^2)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Now they say

> You can cast this particular equation in terms of a derivative of x,
>   and then you integrate with respect to x to solve it. After
>   integration, you wind up with the following
>   $$-x^2=\frac{d(\frac{-x^3}{3})}{dx}$$

I'm a bit lost on this last statement? How do they end up there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something is not right ... that last line, while a true statement does not have a y in it, so you can't use it to solve for y ...  if that is your aim.
Normally the next step is to integrate

So from 
$2-y^2dy=x^2dx$

$\int2-y^2dy=\int x^2dx$

$2y - \frac{1}{3}y^3 = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + c$

Comment: This is the solution to the original ODE. Is this what you the text book was trying to find?

Comment: I found that book using google and read that section and the author does indeed arrive at the same solution however the process is far more convoluted ... probably he was high. I wouldn't waist time with that method.

Comment: Thx @sav for your reply! I edited the post, I think an editor modified it in a way that drove to confusion

Comment: the thing is I'm trying to understand the process because I'm actually learning differential equations and especially avoid being confused later on because I missed some part of it

Comment: The author has poor communication here. "After integration, you wind up with the following " refers to everything that comes next, not just the single line

Comment: so that line which reads -x^2 = d/dx (-x3/3) .
this is not derived from the previous equations. Its just a statement of fact. Again ... I think he was high. the working is very poorly set out.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thx a lot for helping :)